# Set a UITextField from an NSArray

Tags: uitextfield, nsarray

I have tried many variations with no luck. I can NSLog the array and I get this:

```
2011-07-17 00:54:54.886 Widgets[13444:207] <Widget: 0x5e2aad0> (entity: Widget; id: 0x5e0d8e0 <x-coredata://E64A0BCE-2344-4EE1-89CC-164ACD8995D6/Recipe/p115> ; data: {
    success = 1;
    coconutscarried = nil;
    name = "African Swallow";
    uidnumber = "105 ";
})
```

How can I simple set a text field?

Pardon the mess but this is an assortment of code I have tried (messy). The array and text field have been set up in .h/m and bound in IB

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[[swallowArray name] text]); // doesnt work
    //NSLog(@"The string at index is %@.", [self.swallowArray objectAtIndex:0]);//nope...
    for (int i = 0; i < [swallowArray count]; i++) {
        //nameTextField.text = [[swallowArray objectAtIndex:i] uidnumber];
        //NSLog(@"%@",swallowArray.name);
    //}
    //nameTextField.text = [[swallowArray objectAtIndex:0] uidnumber];
    //NSString* strRate = [[swallowArray object] uidnumber];
    nameTextField.text = [nameTextField.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@", %@", [[swallowArray objectAtIndex:i] name]]];

}
```

and many more. This has got to be dead simple, but I am kind of a noob.

thanks!

bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 5 hours of searching, I post here, and find the answer in literally five minutes!

```
NSString *nameFromArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [eventArray valueForKey:@"name"]];
NSLog(@"%@", nameFromArray);
```

Hope this helps someone else!